# Can't deploy to Tomcat - no httpd process

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl, nginx, encryption

I am trying to implement encryption a Tomcat Server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I follow [this advise](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html), and in the `.ebextensions` directory, I add the following files:

**`https-instance.config`**, which contains the `certificate` file and `private key` contents.

**`ssl.conf`**, which contains:

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle.crt"
SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
```

but on the server in `/etc/pki/tls/certs`:

[image]

(In `ssl.conf` I tried changing `"/etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle.crt"` to `"/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"`, but no difference)

**`https-instance-single.config`**, which contains:

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I then try deploy my `war` file, but get:

**Error**

> [Instance: i-04a9fa826b9d8e0a3] Command failed on instance. Return
>   code: 1 Output: httpd: no process found. container_command killhttpd
>   in .ebextensions/https-instance.config failed. For more detail, check
>   /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

**`eb-activity.log`**

> [Application update
>   thewhozoo-1.0.0.39@121/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_theWhoZoo_java/Command
>   killhttpd] : Activity execution failed, because: httpd: no process
>   found    (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)

As you can see, it's complaining about in **`https-instance.config`** there is `httpd: no process found`. Which suggests that there is a problem with:

```
...
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

container_commands:
  killhttpd:
    command: "killall httpd"
  waitforhttpddeath:
    command: "sleep 3"
```

i.e. **there is no httpd process**.

I then read that I need to set up a proxy server on Tomcat, so I follow [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html#java-tomcat-proxy), **Extending the Default nginx Configuration**.

So I add the following:

**`.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/https.conf`**

```
# HTTPS server

server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:80;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

But I still get the same above error (no httpd process).

**More info**

I don't really know what this means, but it looks like something is running on the server:

[image]

and

[image]

where on the server **`/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`**:

```
#
# This is the Apache server configuration file providing SSL support.
# It contains the configuration directives to instruct the server how to
# serve pages over an https connection. For detailing information about these 
# directives see <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html>
# 
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

#
# When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the 
# the HTTPS port in addition.
#
Listen 443

##
##  SSL Global Context
##
##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
##

#   Pass Phrase Dialog:
#   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
#   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is a internal
#   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

#   Inter-Process Session Cache:
#   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism 
#   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

#   Semaphore:
#   Configure the path to the mutual exclusion semaphore the
#   SSL engine uses internally for inter-process synchronization. 
SSLMutex default

#   Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG):
#   Configure one or more sources to seed the PRNG of the 
#   SSL library. The seed data should be of good random quality.
#   WARNING! On some platforms /dev/random blocks if not enough entropy
#   is available. This means you then cannot use the /dev/random device
#   because it would lead to very long connection times (as long as
#   it requires to make more entropy available). But usually those
#   platforms additionally provide a /dev/urandom device which doesn't
#   block. So, if available, use this one instead. Read the mod_ssl User
#   Manual for more details.
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
#SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512

#
# Use "SSLCryptoDevice" to enable any supported hardware
# accelerators. Use "openssl engine -v" to list supported
# engine names.  NOTE: If you enable an accelerator and the
# server does not start, consult the error logs and ensure
# your accelerator is functioning properly. 
#
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
#SSLCryptoDevice ubsec

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

# General setup for the virtual host, inherited from global configuration
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
#ServerName www.example.com:443

# Use separate log files for the SSL virtual host; note that LogLevel
# is not inherited from httpd.conf.
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

#   SSL Protocol support:
# List the enable protocol levels with which clients will be able to
# connect.  Disable SSLv3 access by default:
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

#   SSL Cipher Suite:
# List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
# See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

#   Server Certificate:
# Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
# the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
# pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  A new
# certificate can be generated using the genkey(1) command.
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt

#   Server Private Key:
#   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
#   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
#   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
#   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key

#   Server Certificate Chain:
#   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
#   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
#   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
#   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
#   certificate for convinience.
#SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server-chain.crt

#   Certificate Authority (CA):
#   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
#   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
#   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

#   Client Authentication (Type):
#   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
#   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
#   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
#   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
#SSLVerifyClient require
#SSLVerifyDepth  10

#   Access Control:
#   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
#   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
#   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
#   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
#   for more details.
#<Location />
#SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
#            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
#            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
#           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
#</Location>

#   SSL Engine Options:
#   Set various options for the SSL engine.
#   o FakeBasicAuth:
#     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
#     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
#     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
#     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
#     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
#   o ExportCertData:
#     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
#     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
#     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
#     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
#     into CGI scripts.
#   o StdEnvVars:
#     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
#     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
#     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
#     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
#     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
#   o StrictRequire:
#     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
#     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
#     and no other module can change it.
#   o OptRenegotiate:
#     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
#     directives are used in per-directory context. 
#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

#   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
#   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
#   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
#   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
#   approach you can use one of the following variables:
#   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
#     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
#     SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
#     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
#     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
#   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
#     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
#     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
#     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
#     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
#     works correctly. 
#   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
#   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
#   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
#   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
#   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
#   "force-response-1.0" for this.
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
#   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
#   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

(Unfortunately I cannot deploy to the server and I am under time pressure - should I delete the entire environment and start again on AWS?)

**UPDATE**

On the advise below, I add Elastic Load Balancing to my server, set up https with a certificate issued by Amazon. I test my app, and the url is accessible under `https`...Yay!

However, when I access it, it shows:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Why is it "Not Secure"?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for *programming* questions. Your questions are more suited to serverfault.

Comment: Thanks James, didn't know about that. Will post my question there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't ask the question on `serverfault` as I need a reputation of at least `10` (which I don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Elastic Beanstalk I'd totally recommend you to use the Elastic Load balancer to take care of the encryption. Use HTTP layer between the VM and ELB and then from the ELB to the client, use HTTPS.

You can generate the certificates for free on AWS and upload them in the ELB.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the advise. The reason I am not using an `Elastic Load Balancer` is because it's not available on AWS's Free-tier. I have a limited budget, and have read that other people have got `https` working on a single instance.

Comment: In that case, better create a EC2 instance and deploy the App in tomcat. Configure the Tomcat accordingly with the HTTP and HTTPS connector and the Java Keystore. It's going to be easier.

Comment: I am using Ealstic Beanstalk on an `EC2` instance (sorry I wan't clear above). I am not sure how to `configure a HTTP and HTTPS connector and the Java Keystore`, I thought that's what I was doing?

Comment: What you're doing is embed a proxy in your app using nginx and route the requests to Tomcat.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow that advise.

Comment: Also, afaik the ELB should be included on the free-tier. I've done that in the past.

Comment: Sorry, what's `afaik the ELB`?

Comment: as far as I know the Elastic Load Balancer

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest is: create a new environment with web-tier (instead of worker) with Tomcat. Remove from the project the .ebextensions. Upload the .war file. On the Load balancer add the certificate as shown in the documents attached to the answer.

Comment: Yes you're correct the `ELB` is available under free tier. I will look at that option.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-limits.html

Comment: Yes you're correct the `ELB` is available under free tier. I will look at that option.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-limits.html

Comment: I got `https` working using an ELB. However, when I access the server via `https`, it says it's "Not Secure". The browser also asked if I would like to proceed etc. Please see UPDATE above for details.

Comment: Did you verify that you are using https://? Also, if you click on the non-secure icon it'll prompt you with more insights about what exactly is happening. Most likely you're fetching non-secure content